# Trailer tail lights still on when ignition is off

Tags: electrical, lights, volvo, trailer, v70

After having attaching a trailer hitch to a Volvo V70 2005 the tail lights keep glowing even when ignition is off. Therefore I have two questions:

1. Is it normal on some cars? If not  any ideas what might be wrong? Tried with some of those extra lights for bicycle carrier racks. Same things. Lights don't turns off.
2. Will the battery drain even when the trailer is unplugged if the car somehow sends signals to the trailer socket.

Comment: Have you checked the plugs / sockets are correctly configured? Note, there are two sockets on newer/many cars are you using the correct one? Also if the trailer is disconnected from the car it will not drain the battery. But if there is something else left on in the car that will...

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not sure. How to I find out if it's correct and where do I configure it?

Comment: Well, start with a search, one result is : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_standards_for_trailer_connectors or check with your favorite volvo dealer...